# Django admin list edit

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I encountered some weird behavior when using admin `list_editable` with a restricting custom manager. Each time I am trying to save list changes in admin, I get the message: *Please correct the errors below.*

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this error message?

Here is a minimal sample:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class RestrictedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(RestrictedManager, self).get_queryset().none()


class MyModel(models.Model):
    on = models.BooleanField()

    objects = RestrictedManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin, site
from models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_editable = ('on',)
    list_display = ('id', 'on',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return MyModel.all_objects

site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

If you wonder, why am I using a `none()` default queryset, I don't. I used `none()` only to simplify the example. The issue occurs with any object filtered out by the default manager.

Comment: This seems to be outdated as there is no ModelAdmin in django.contrib.admin anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't tested this yet, but probably the problem is, that you've overridden the default manager.

From the Django docs: [Default managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#default-managers)

> If you use custom Manager objects, take note that the first Manager Django encounters (in the order in which they’re defined in the model) has a special status. Django interprets the first Manager defined in a class as the “default” Manager, and several parts of Django (including dumpdata) will use that Manager exclusively for that model. As a result, it’s a good idea to be careful in your choice of default manager in order to avoid a situation where overriding get_queryset() results in an inability to retrieve objects you’d like to work with.

So using your "UnrestrictedManager" first and your Custom Manager as second should do the trick.

Comment: It seems that my approach is discouraged by Django. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by creating a proxy model with a simple manager.

```
class UnrestrictedMyModel(MyModel):
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

site.register(UnrestrictedMyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

But I am still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have all `list_display` as `list_editable`. 
You can:

1. make one of `list_editable` field to be a non-editable link by adding it to `list_display_links`
2. add `id` into `list_display`